Ubuntu 24.10 under Wayland, and Nvidia
Ubuntu 24.10
Wayland
Nvidia MX330
Nvidia 560.35.03

I was led to believe that the prior problems of running a Nvidia card were fixed under Wayland in Ubuntu 24.10.
So I upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10 and ran under Xorg, solved some various upgrade issues, and it seemed to run fine.
Then I enabled Wayland. With some minor problems, it ran fine. I decided to put the Nvidia into "Performance mode", and it seemed fine until I checked nvidia-smi and noted that only gnome-shell was being accelerated.
Here I show via the cli that the Nvidia Performance Mode is selected...

Here is show the GUI showing Performance Mode under Xorg...

Here is nvidia-smi running under Xorg... note the full compliment of processes that are accelerated... whereas under Wayland it only shows gnome-shell...

So my question is... is this a Wayland or Nvidia problem? What steps might I take to further troubleshoot this and fix it?
Update: So I upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10 and ran under Xorg, solved some various upgrade issues, and it seemed to run fine.
I find that I can't open folders on my Desktop, in Xorg, in "Performance Mode". "On-Demand" works fine.

Short answer... the NVIDIA drivers are a mess.
Three workarounds... pick one...

run NVIDIA in On-Demand mode in Xorg

install Nemo and switch prefs in the "Desktop Icons NG" (DING) extension to use Nemo in Xorg

use Wayland with NVIDIA in Performance Mode.



Nivida GPU, with 560.35.03 on performance mode. Worked fine on Xorg but did not work at all on Wayland. Adding the parameter DRI_PRIME=1 to /etc/enviroment and rebooting did the job for me!

All this does is to force the use of the Nvidia GPU, instead of any built-in Intel GPU. Since Nvidia 560 is a beta version, I'd recommend using a non-beta release, removing your DRI_PRIME=1, rebooting, and see if the problem is still fixed.

I removed the parameter from /etc/enviroment. Now I add it to the command line whenever I want to force use Nvidia GPU. But in nvtop it seems like both the Nvidia GPU and the Intel integrated GPU are being used together when I add the parameter. I am definitely looking forward for any updates.
